# Tableau remove row

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

could someone please advise how to remove blanks and zero for 2020 difference and percentage difference. I only wanted to find the difference from 2021 to 2020 where difference would be shown in one row only below 2021 and percentage difference in another row.

[image]

Comment: Please give some sample data and desired output for that sample data!

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the 2020 label, and see if you have a “hide” option